# Import dijit/dojo widgets into worklight palette

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I've been working with IBM Worklight for the last month and I discovered that even if I imported the Dojo toolkit when I created my hybrid app, I can't see dijit components in my palette, and some dojo/dojox components cause errors.

Here is my config :

- Windows XP
- Eclipse SDK Version: 3.7.2
- IBM Worklight 5.0.5
- Dojo version 1.8.1-20121024

Therefore I got errors when launching my app :

*Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*

*URL/ipad/1.0/default/dojox/dgauges/components/green/HorizontalLinearGauge.js*

(I wanted to display a slider and only found this gauge)

But I do have the dojo folder in my project (with dijit/dojo/dojox folders inside).

Anyone knows how to fix this ?

Cheers

Comment: Any chance you can try with the almost 2-years newer version, Worklight 6.1.0 (you can obtain it from Eclipse > Help > Eclipse Marketplace > search for "worklight"). Worklight 5.0.5 is totally OLD. See if it still happens to you.

Comment: Unfortunately I suppose I can't change for now since I have a pro computer... Don't you have any idea about this ? Can't figure out how to "include" these files to server, and I guess I'm not supposed to, as they are part of the project.

Comment: I don't even have this version installed anymore. :) It is **not** an encouraged version to use... Let me see...

Answer (score 0):

1. I have used the Worklight Studio 5.0.5.1 wizard to create a project and application that includes Dojo and added the iPad environment.
2. Next, looking at the Dojo Palette, I see a slider widget. I drag it to my HTML:
   [image]
3. `Run As > Build All and Deploy` and previewing the environment in the MBS shows the slider:
   [image]

I do not have Xcode on this machine so this is the best I can do right now.
Are you sure you do not see a `slider` widget?

Comment: Sorry yes I do see a slider, but I reffered to this documentation 
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/HorizontalSlider.html#dijit-form-horizontalslider

instead of this one : 
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/mobile/Slider.html

as the first one fits more my needs. Any chance I can use the dijit one with my Worklight version ?

And why can't I use the HorizontalLinearGauge ? This is actually the same question than "Why do I have a 404 error from the server which can't find claro.css even if I imported the dojo toolkit"

Comment: Comment on nsand's answer. Maybe he will know.

Answer (score 0):

If you were looking for the dijit form Horizontal Slider, you can right click in the palette's contents and click `Customize...` In the Customize Palette dialog, select the `Dojo Form Widgets` category, and uncheck `Hide`. When you expand `Dojo Form Widgets`, you can select `Horizontal Slider` and uncheck `Hide`. Click `OK`, and these items should show up in the palette.

But for a slider on a mobile page, Idan's suggestion of using a Dojo Mobile Slider is probably better than the dijit slider.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the dijit fits more my needs :/ Any chance I can use it ?

Comment: I did it but I still got 404 errors, here is a pic, may be clearer [link](http://hpics.li/bd9d0ca)

Comment: Found [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014926149) about my problem, but can't figure out how to solve this as the example is in Worklight 6.1

Comment: Where do you see 6.1 in the link you've posted?

Comment: I followed the link in the last post which leads to the [Worklight Doc](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/c_anatomy_of_an_ibm_worklight_ap.html).
Then if you select **Login form and authenticator** you will be redirected to an example of the charting widget, but this example is in WL 6.1. But I found the examples of WL 5.0.5 in the menu on the right of the page, but it isn't related to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

To improve build performance, applications with Dojo dictate which files to include in the build using the `build-dojo.xml` file. By default, it is optimized for mobile development. If you'd like to include the HorizontalSlider, the easiest way is to uncomment `<include name="dojo/dijit-layer.js.compressed.js"/>`, but leave the `<include>` elements after that commented out. That will give you a patternset of "dojo/dojo.js.compressed.js", "dojo/core-web-layer.js.compressed.js", and "dojo/dijit-layer.js.compressed.js".

If you've used the Palette to drag and drop the HorizontalSlider, it should have added references to dijit.css and claro.css in the application's markup. So these resources will need to be added to your application to style the widget. You could do this manually by copying the dijit/themes/claro/ directory and dijit/themes/dijit.css file into your application. But as we saw, the build-dojo.xml file automates adding these things to the build. In your build-dojo.xml file, find the patternset `dojo.resources.loose-modules`. And add the following includes:

```
<include name="dijit/themes/claro/**"/>
<include name="dijit/themes/dijit.css"/>
```

Save the `build-dojo.xml` file.

Now you need to update your application's JS file. In wlCommonInit, the layer files are required. There is an array the includes what you would need for mobile development. You will need to add another layer to the array: "dojo/dijit-layer". So it should look something like:

```
require([ "dojo/core-web-layer", "dojo/mobile-ui-layer", "dojo/mobile-compat-layer", "dojo/dijit-layer" ], dojoInit);
```

Save your application's JS file and preview your application as you normally would. This should fix the 404 problems and render the HorizontalSlider widget.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. As I deleted the Sliders I imported into my page and still had this issue I'll try your idea. I'll reimport Sliders into my page. It may be caused by a wrong import. I'll let you know

Comment: Cleaned projet, removed my sliders from the HTML page + the two imports 

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dijit/themes/dijit.css">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">`

in the **header**, and removed the two **includes** in the dojo XML file. Still got errors

Comment: Actually every single widget I add that doesn't belong to the default loaded widgets causes an error to fire with the 404 code. Did I miss something ? I don't think I am supposed to do anything except drag and drop the widget into my HTML page.

Comment: Oops, I forgot a step. In your application's JS file, you'll see a require in wlCommonInit. In addition to the changes in your build-dojo.xml, you will need to add another module to the end of the array: "dojo/dijit-layer". I've edited the answer to include this step.

Comment: I was pretty sure I had to do that kind of import, but I tried by myself in the `dojoInit()` method instead of `wlCommonInit()`.

Anyway thanks a lot as I don't have 404 errors anymore in the Chromium simulator, and the slider is the one I need in the **Worklight simulator**, but the it still isn't displayed in the **Chromium simulator** (even if his div can be seen in the Elements tab of the console)

May it be related to this error ? `core-web-layer.js:55
dojo/parser::parse() error                              
message: Unable to resolve constructor for: dojox.mobile.FixedSplitter` Idea ?